# Why does the unary bit inversion operator not invert the value of a BOOL?

Tags: objective-c, boolean, bit-manipulation

I want to invert the value of a `BOOL` every time I detect a tap. The default value of the `BOOL` is `NO` and the first time I tap it inverts it to `YES`. On subsequent taps the value stays as `YES`.

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL isDayOrNight; //property in timeDayChart object.

self.timeDayChart.isDayOrNight = ~self.timeDayChart.isDayOrNight; //This is done in a VC.
```

I had to change it to this:

```
self.timeDayChart.isDayOrNight = !self.timeDayChart.isDayOrNight;
```

to achieve my desired results. I would like to know why `~` did not work as expected.

Comment: Note that `~someVal` is essentially the same as `allOnesVal - someVal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BOOL is defined as a signed char in objc.h:

```
typedef signed char     BOOL;
```

and YES and NO are defined like so:

```
#define YES             (BOOL)1
#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

So ~YES is -2, which is not the same as NO.

Comment: And, in fact, ~NO is -1, which, while it behaves like YES is not the canonical value for YES.

Comment: Good, through answer. (voted) The short form of this answer is "Because '~' is a bitwise operator, not a logical negation operator, so it is not **SUPPOSED TO* do logical negation."

Comment: Thank you all very much.

Comment: @DuncanC - Yep, just remember that the bitwise operators are not logical. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In (Objective-)C(++) when a Boolean value is required, such as in an `if` or as an operand to `&&`, actually take an integer value and interpret 0 as false and non-zero as true. The logical, relational and equality operators all also return integers, using 0 for false and 1 for true.

Objective-C's `BOOL` is a synonym for `signed char`, which is an *integer* type, while `NO` and `YES` are defined as 0 and 1 respectively.

As you correctly state `~` is the bit inversion operator. If you invert any integer containing both 0's and 1's the result will also do so. Any value containing a 1 bit is treated as true, and inverting any such value other than all 1's produces a value with at least one 1 bit which is also interpreted as true.

If you start with all 0's then repeated inversion should go all 1's, all 0's, all 1's - which is true, false, true etc. (but *not* YES, NO, YES, etc.). So if you are starting with 0 then either you are not always using inversion or you are testing explicitly for `YES` rather than true.

However what you should be using, as you figured out, is `!` - logical negation - which maps 0 to 1 and non-0 to 0 and so handles "true" values other than 1 correctly.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Find a book about the C language. Check what it says about the ~ operator and the ! operator. ~ inverts all bits in an integer, and BOOL is defined as an integer type. So NO = all bits zero will be changed to all bits set, which is not the same as YES, and YES = all bits zero except the last bit = 1 will be changed to all bits set except the last bit = 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using this idiom to toggle a BOOL value:

```
self.timeDayChart.isDay = self.timeDayChart.isDay ? NO : YES;
```

(I deliberately changed the naming of your property)

Comment: Using `!` is perfectly fine for toggling a BOOL.

Comment: It's prefect only since the NOT operator returns 1 for any value which is not zero, and 1 happens to be equal to `YES`. If `YES` wouldn't be equal `1` the NOT operator wouldn't be perfect, IMO ;)  This avoids the common pitfall when doing things like this: `if (x == YES) { ... }` and x happens to be 0xFF or something like this.

Comment: Doesn't much matter what YES is.  It must react like a C bool value regardless, or `if` statements and the like would not work.

Comment: Boolean expressions in C always evaluate to either 0 or 1. So, you can assign a boolean expression to a BOOL, and it equals either `YES` or `NO`. But only because `YES` equals 1. So it matters. ;)

Comment: The universal truth is that a boolean in a C-ish language should be zero for FALSE and non-zero for TRUE.  If Objective-C's implementation violated that it all sorts of stuff would break.  Otherwise, it doesn't matter in most cases what YES/TRUE/true is.